# Catching errors from one function inside another JavaScript React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, try-catch

I have two functions, login (in fileB.js):

```
export const login = async (data) => {
  try {
    const response = await auth.login(data);
    return response;
  } catch (e) {
    return new Error(e);
  }
};
```

and loginProcess (in fileA.js):

```
const loginProcess = (data) => {
    login(data)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {

        }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        setError(true);
      });
  };
```

If I have an error inside `login()` function it returns `new Error(e)` but inside `loginProcess()` the error from `login()` is not caught by `catch` but with `then`. I need to catch the `new Error` from `login()` inside `catch` in `loginProcess()`, how can I fix it?

Comment: "*it returns new Error(e)*" - and that's wrong. One should not `return` errors, one should `throw` them as exceptions.

Comment: Also it's not logical to wrap the error in another `Error` - why do you even `catch` this error inside the function at all?

Answer (score 4):

You are converting promise rejection into promise fulfilment by *returning* an error object.

Retuning a non-promise value from the `catch` block will *fulfil* the promise returned by the `login` function with the return value of the `catch` block.

To reject the promise returned by the `login` function:

- *Re-throw* the error caught by the `catch` block, or
- Remove the `try-catch` block from the `login` function and let the calling code handle the error.

`login` function could be re-written as:

```
export const login = (data) => {
    return auth.login(data);
};
```

---

I suggest that you choose the second option and re-write the `login` function as shown above. There is no need for a `catch` block that just re-throws the error.

Comment: I just changed ```return``` to ```throw``` and it works now, thanks!

Comment: I suggest writing `return await auth.login(data)` so the `login` function doesn't get removed from the stack trace and it doesn't set a refactoring trap in case someone adds back the `try/catch` at some point in the future (for instance to catch _specific_ errors) or tries assigning the response to a variable instead of directly returning it, or appending something like `|| somethingElse`. (See [this issue](https://github.com/standard/standard/issues/1442).)

Comment: @CherryDT IMHO, `login` function doesn't needs to be `async` at all. `login` function can just return the promise and the calling code can do the necessary error handling.

Comment: That would obscure the fact that it's an asynchronous operation which most likely should be `await`ed by its caller because now the type wouldn't even be an `AsyncFunction` anymore. Yes technically it's correct what you say, I just think it can cause mistakes later on.