# Promise.allSettled returns catch as fullfilled

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I am making https requests using a function `batchRequest` that collects the promises in batches with `Promise.allSettled` and sends them to the `apiRequest` function that makes the actual calls with axios.

On the `batchRequest` function I send an array of urls to the HTTP request function and await the results. Then I use the `Promise.allSettled` `status` to identify the `rejected` ones. But when the `apiRequest` catches as error `Promise.allSettled` sees it as `status: fullfilled`

```js
async function batchRequest(data, index) {
  console.log(`Running... ${index} round`)
  while (data.length) {

    // Batched request according to concurrent setting
    const batch = data
      .splice(0, settings.concurrent)
      .map((url) => apiRequest(url, index))

    const results = await Promise.allSettled(batch)

    results.forEach(({ status, value, reason }) => {
      if (status === 'fulfilled') {
        console.log(value) // I get both the try and catch here from `apiRequest`
      }
      if (status === 'rejected') {
        console.log(reason)
        // I never get anything here
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Api request function

```js
async function apiRequest(url, index) {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios('https://api-end-point')
    return 'All good' + url
  } catch (error) {
    const status = error.response?.status ?? 'No response'
    return  `Error: ${status}, ${url}`
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't return the error. throw it!

Comment: You are converting promise rejection into promise fulfilment by returning an error object Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69325096/6094348. You could just have a single line `return await axios('https://api-end-point')` or `return axios('https://api-end-point')` inside the `apiRequest` function and use the `try-catch` inside the `batchRequest` function.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, you could also replace: `apiRequest(url, index)` with `axios('https://api-end-point')` and get rid of `apiRequest` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't return the error. throw it!

```
async function apiRequest(url, index) {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios('https://api-end-point')
    return 'All good' + url
  } catch (error) {
    const status = error.response?.status ?? 'No response'
    throw  `Error: ${status}, ${url}` // <------------change here
  }
}
```

Comment: But now I am getting an error whenever throwing inside a catch